# How do I maintain equal hot and neutral paths when wiring 3-way switches with lights on both ends using a /4 wire between them

Tags: electrical, multiway-switch

This is a follow-up question to the answer by Harper - Reinstate Monica https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/110881/181433 the suggestion to use a /4 wire is what I have been trying to implement in practice but the solution eludes me because it seems the hot and neutral paths for the light attached to Box A are different lengths.

The neutral hooked to light in Box A is attached to the incoming neutral but its hot is coming from Box B where the other (switched hot) end of the 3-way switch is located.  This would imply that the neutral is significantly shorter length than the switched hot to light in Box A.  Is this allowed because all conductors are contained within the same cable or is there some other reason?

Comment: No reason the hot and neutral paths need to be the same length. Suppose the line hot and neutral enter the circuit in the ceiling fixture box. In the past the neutral would go directly to the neutral of the fixture and the line hot would go to the switch and switched hot return in the same cable. Much longer path for the hot. Nowadays a neutral must go to the switch box but one would presumably still have a short neutral to the fixture.

Comment: I you are worried about total instantaneous current in a cable being zero (respecting the sign), the instantaneous line hot and switched hot will be in different directions and will cancel out.

Comment: I was reading this statement in the answer "That is because in any cable, currents must be equal (cancel each other out)" and was took that as all hot/neutral lengths had to be equal conductor length but it seems that just mean hot and neutral have to be in the same Romex that makes sense then

Answer (score 2):

They don't need to be equal length the current in each Romex or conduit just needs to balance.

to the lamp = from the lamp

to the switch = from the switch

to the supply =  from the supply